# draw an arbitrary line with OpenGL(i.e. no limit on axis range)

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I want to draw a 2D line with parameters defined by user. But the range of x and y axis is [-1,1].

How can I draw the line that can be completely displayed in the window? I used `gluOrtho2D(-10.0, 10.0, -10.0, 10.0)` but it doesn't seem a good choice because the range is dynamic according to the parameters.

For example, the line is `y=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d`. the range of x is [1, 100].

My code is:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include<windows.h>

#include <gl/glut.h>

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double a, b, c, d;
void init(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluOrtho2D(-10.0, 10.0, -10.0, 10.0);
}

double power(double x, int p) {
    double y = 1.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < p; ++i) {
        y *= x;
    }
    return y;
}

void linesegment(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
    glPointSize(1);

    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
        double y = a * power(i, 3) + b * power(i, 2) + c * i + d;
        glVertex2f(i, y);
    }
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char**argv)

{
    if (argc < 4) {
        cout << "should input 4 numbers" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    a = atof(argv[1]);
    b = atof(argv[2]);
    c = atof(argv[3]);
    d = atof(argv[4]);

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowPosition(50, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 300);
    glutCreateWindow("AnExample");

    init();

    glutDisplayFunc(linesegment);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: just a suggestion. you might want to consider learning [modern opengl](https://learnopengl.com/) instead of 10+ year deprecated opengl

Comment: *"the range is dynamic according to the parameters."* - What?

Comment: If you want to draw a line then use [`GL_LINES`, `GL_LINE_STRIP` ...](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive). If you want to draw in window (pixel) coordinates, where the top left is (0, 0), the the orthographic projection has to be `gluOrtho2D(0.0, 400.0, 300.0, 0.0);`

Comment: @Rabbid76 hi, I mean when a,b,c,d changes, the maximum value of y changes. So the parameters of gluOrtho2D can't be static.

Comment: @IHaveAProblem Then you've to set a new orthographic projection `glLoadIdentity();` `gluOrtho2D(...);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting projection matrix is not a one-time-only operation. You can change it anytime you like. As a matter of fact, the way you do `init` is strongly discouraged. Just set the projection parameters in your drawing function. Also use standard library functions and don't roll your own. No need to implement `power` yourself. Just use the `pow` standard library function. Last but not least, use double buffering; for it gives better performance, and has better compatibility.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <windows.h>

#include <gl/glut.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double a, b, c, d;
double x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max; // <<<<---- fill these per your needs

void linesegment(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max, -1, 1);

    glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
    glPointSize(1);

    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
        double y = a * pow(i, 3) + b * pow(i, 2) + c * i + d;
        glVertex2f(i, y);
    }
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}
```